# Deleted all files in fresh repo with accidental git reset --hard

Tags: git

I was working on some code, which didn't have any kind of git repo set up. I ran:

`git init`
`git remote add origin http://giturl.git`

then I ran `git add -A` and realized I forgot to create a `.gitignore` file.

For some reason I ran `git reset --hard` ...oops, that was dumb.

It deleted all the files in the folder, and I have no clue how, or if it's even possible to get them back.

Comment: Did you do a commit? It's not possible to run git reset until after your first commit because the HEAD ref (branch?) doesn't exist yet. You will get the error: fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref. If you did commit, then just reset master branch back to that first initial commit.

Comment: I did not make any commits. Just ran `git add -A`. Looks like git fsck was the ticket.

Comment: Interesting, I tried to replicate and could not reproduce your scenario, what version of git are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I was saved by running `git fsck --lost-found`. Because I had at least ran `git add -A`, I just had to sift through the blobs to get the data I needed back.